# How do you fly with elytra wings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know how to put on the elytra wings, but I don't know to acually fly. I do know that you have to go to a high mountain or structure but once you are there, how do you start taking flight?

Comment: If I google your question title, I not only get the result, but even a special text box containing exactly what you want, before the rest of the results. It's hard to miss.

Comment: Google has become a very interesting thing...

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the simple way is to go to a high spot, jump off, then press space while you are falling. This activates the elytra, but you can use a firework rocket (crafted with a piece of paper on top of a piece of gunpowder) to boost you. Hold the firework rocket in your hand, and then right click (while the elytra is activated) to boost yourself.

Alternatively, if you can't find a good spot (mountain for example) then simple double-tap space with the elytra on and then right click while holding the firework rocket. (You need to be looking upwards for this to work).

By the way, a firework rocket activated with an elytra (in flight) will boost you in the direction you look.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to fly with Elytra wings is jump, and then press space bar in mid-air.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific with this answer? More description, if possible? Short and sweet doesn't always suffice, especially here on Stack Exchange.